# Expirence store date time in booking engine

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I’m developing a booking online web application in many countries and cities. I have an issue about store date time in database.

A rate is available in between 10/8/2018 and 31/8/2018, my timezone is +7.

when save to database, the rate will be 9/8/2018 17:00:00 and 30/8/2018 17:00:00.

What will happen if the app have many users coming from the timezone different?

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset and not DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question the rightway, then it depends on where you try to get the date. If you try to get the date from the client than it will be the timezone where the user comes from. If you try to get the date from your server when the user do something in the app, then it will be the timezone the server is located.

I hope i understood your question right, if not let me know.

Greetings.